# How do I get the correct time in php

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

Why every time I get the time with the code below it shows 1 hour before the correct time. I have the same issue with other languages like javascript Every time i want to get the current time it shows 1 hour past?

every time I try to get time on my system on any timezones I get 1 hour last i.a in utc if the worldwide time is 12:00:00 it shows me 11:00:00 on utc and i have the same problem with all timezones.
I tested this code

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('H:i:s', time());
```

Comment: What is your "correct time" compared to [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc)? In other word, how does the time you want deviate from the time given in the page I linked to?

Comment: post edited and i explained more.thanks

Comment: When I run that code right now I get `13` for the hours, what do you get? https://3v4l.org/klgDG#v8.2.7.

Comment: I get 12 for hour in local system but in the link you sent is 13

Comment: Can you check the server's clock?

Comment: my system time is Asia/Tehran 17:07 but on the same timezone also i get 16:07

Comment: Ah, that explains it. You need to update your time-zone file. On 22 Sep 2022 there was [a late change to the summer time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/iran/tehran).

Comment: Thanks.after updating windows it works perfectly.

Comment: This feels like such a bizarre problem that could really frustrate someone else if they run into it, that I think it deserves a concrete answer. I know I'd be pulling my hair out on it. I  don't expect the answer to be overly complicated either. @KIKOSoftware, would you mind writing that up?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, it is quite bizarre, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Iran the government [abolished daylight saving time (DST)](https://livingintehran.com/2022/09/21/daylight-saving-time-ends-in-iran/) on 22 September 2022.

Any software created before that date could therefore not have included this change. Clearly your server/computer contains such an outdated piece of software and still applies DTS.

In most case a simple update of the operating systems will rectify the problem. In Linux the time zones are stored in [a small database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). For how to update Linux see: [Downloading the tz database](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html).